# insert multiple rows in database using pdo's

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
insert into test (sometext) values ("?"),("?")
$a= array("weird' text","sdfa");
```

I want to insert text into the table test in column sometext using bind parameter and **I do not want the execute statement in a loop.** I cannot implode the array in ("?"),("?") form as the query might crash coz the text can be composed of quotes.

So is there a way to achieve this using PDO in one(1) execute statement?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot implode the array in ("?"),("?") form as the query might crash coz the text can be composed of quotes.

The prepared statements are there to solve quoting/escaping problems.

This syntax is wrong<sup>1</sup>:

```
insert into test (sometext) values ("?"),("?")
```

You don't have to wrap parameters by quotes, you have to write query in this form:

```
INSERT INTO test (sometext) VALUES (?),(?)
```

Then, you can use `implode()` without worrying about quotes:

```
$a     = array( "weird' text", "sdfa" );
$query = "INSERT INTO test (sometext) VALUES (" . implode( "),(", array_fill( 0, count( $a ), "?" ) ) . ")";
$stmt  = $db->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute( $a );
```

As alternative, you can use `substr` and `str_repeat` instead of `implode`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (sometext) VALUES " . substr( str_repeat( "(?),", count( $a ) ), 0, -1 );
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Using `insert into test (sometext) values ("?"),("?")` you insert in your fields literally two question marks.

Answer (score 0):

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $field1, $field2, $field3);

// set parameters and execute

$field1 = "test";

$field2 = "test2";

$field3 = "test@test.cc";
$stmt->execute();